# French version of Ubuntu-one for Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I'm a French new user and I'd like to show Ubuntu-one working on Windows for newbies. The problem is that the Windows application is downloadable in English and I’d like it in French.

Is there a French version of Ubuntu-one for Windows ?

Comment: Wouldn't it just adjust to the systems locale?, i remember having Ubuntu one in spanish.

Comment: it is not Ubuntu-one on Linux ... but on Windows

Comment: Yes i did meant on Windows...

Comment: I haven't seen any language pack for it. And no entry to change it in any menu

Answer (score 1):

We have not yet translated the windows version to other languages. We intend to do it once we sync our Windows and Linux codebases, and can use the translations for both.